# Automatically retry failed Specflow tests on TeamCity, without showing a run failure if the retry passes?

Tags: automation, teamcity, specflow

We use Specflow as our automation suite, and we have TeamCity configured to run our tests.

Specflow gives us the option to automatically retry tests that fail. The problem I have is that if a test fails but the retry passes, the entire run shows as having failed, because of that initial failure of the test (even though the retry passed).

Is there a way I can make TeamCity show the run as having passed, if a test failed but its retry passed?

Comment: what test runner do you use? (NUnit/SpecFlow etc.)

Comment: How are you executing the SpecFlow+Runner in TeamCity? Is it via vstest.console.exe or like it is documented here: http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-TeamCity/

Comment: @AndreasWillich We're executing out tests how it's specified in the specflow documentation.

Comment: @TomasPanik We're using specflow as the test runner